# respond_to mostrar errors com relacionamentos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Minha dúvida é apenas sobre a arquitetura de como retornar o erro pra view.
Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```ruby
    class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :responsavel, class_name: 'Pessoa',  foreign_key: 'responsavel_id'
    end

    class Alunos < Pessoa
    end
```

Com esses models, eu tenho o seguinte formulário

.
    <%= form_for @aluno, html: {role: 'form', class: 'form-horizontal', :'data-turbo-form' => 'true'} do |f| %>
    
       <%= render partial: 'pessoas/form', locals: {f: f} %>

Preencha a baixo os dados do responsável desse aluno.

Responsável
            <%= f.fields_for(:responsavel, @aluno.responsavel) do |responsavel| %>
            <%= responsavel.hidden_field :id, value: @aluno.responsavel.id unless @aluno.responsavel.nil? %>
                <%= render partial: 'pessoas/form', locals: {f: responsavel} %>
                <% end %>
        
    
    <% end %>
    .

O formulário `pessoas/form` é uma partial view que é compartilhado entre outras views.

Desse jeito, toda requisição é feita para `Aluno#create` e eu faço o seguinte:

```ruby
class AlunosController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @aluno = Aluno.new(aluno_params)

        # e se aqui o model parar nas validações definidas? Como eu gerenciaria os erros do responsavel?
        set_responsavel responsavel_params

        respond_to do |format|
            # adiciono várias outras checagens aqui nessa condição para ver se o model responsável possui errros?
            if @aluno.save
                format.html { redirect_to alunos_path }
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @aluno }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                # como eu varia o merge dos erros do responsável com o erro do aluno? responsavel.errors << @aluno.erros?
                format.json { render json: @aluno.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def create_responsavel(params)
        responsavel = Pessoa.create params
    end

    def update_responsavel(params)
        responsavel = Pessoa.update params[:id], params
        responsavel
    end

    def set_responsavel(resp_params)
        unless resp_params[:nome].nil?
            responsavel = (resp_params[:id].nil? && create_responsavel(resp_params)) || update_responsavel(resp_params)
            @aluno.responsavel_id = responsavel.id unless responsavel.blank?
        end
    end
end
```

Dese jeito, crio primeiro o responsável e depois eu atualizo ele no aluno.
 A questão é, se eu tentar salvar primeiro o responsável e der um erro, como eu faço o merge dos erros do `responsavel` com o erros do `@aluno`?

Não haverá apenas o relacionamento `responsavel` com o Aluno, futuramente terá `Nota` e `Matricula`. Acredito que tenho que seguir a mesma linha de raciocínio para os outros relacionamentos, certo?